# Firefox и Chrome по разному отображают flex-block или что я делаю не так?

Tags: css

Вот такой код:

```css
fieldset {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  display: flex;
}

div {
  padding: 32px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

fieldset div:first-child {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .2);
}

fieldset div:last-child {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, .2);
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer congue volutpat fermentum. Phasellus faucibus ornare purus sed condimentum. Donec finibus iaculis enim ac finibus. Donec nec quam elementum, pharetra eros sed, venenatis orci. Vestibulum
    convallis mi non dolor pharetra, vitae dictum massa tincidunt. Cras id dignissim massa. Sed bibendum nisl turpis, id ornare orci ultricies vehicula. Vestibulum tristique, est vitae cursus tempus, justo libero sodales nisl, quis faucibus sem urna eget
    nisl. Maecenas tincidunt mauris quis diam consectetur eleifend.
  </div>
  <div>
    Integer eleifend libero maximus, tempor ante sit amet, tempus turpis. Cras aliquet gravida risus, ac posuere turpis ultrices at. Fusce a rutrum quam. Vivamus consectetur sagittis gravida. Aliquam porta tellus quis urna luctus, non cursus erat aliquet.
    Morbi et scelerisque ex, vitae bibendum quam. Vivamus eget accumsan erat.
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Вот что видим в браузерах.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что за бред происходит? Или я может не вижу какого-то явного косяка?

Comment: Если заменить fieldset на div, то всё одинаково. Видимо, какая-то разница в поведении fieldset

Comment: @andreymal это очевидно. но в чем дело-то с `fieldset`?

Comment: Это баг https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=375693

Comment: Это баг https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=262679

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078681/why-cant-fieldset-be-flex-containers

Comment: Не проверял, но судя  по статье, если я правильно понял своим скудным английским, эта проблема и с гридами

Comment: С тегом `button` та же фигня

Comment: И какой смысл использовании `fieldset` без  `legend`?

Comment: @Air это модельный код. `legend` удален, чтобы не отвлекал внимание.

Comment: Оберни контент дивом и будет все работать как надо

Comment: @Air костыль, но ладно, раз это баг, тогда можно. ))

Comment: Да ладно тебе. Один див не костыль....))))